# Cheatsheet and best practices for team members online

Tags: knowledge-organization

We are a small company. We do web development. I'm looking for some solution where we can write best practices, tutorials and cheatsheet for all members.

**EXAMPLE:**

One section would be **Ubuntu** and there would be articles like:

- python36 - how to install
- gunicorn - how to configure gunicorn

For now, it seems that some private wiki would work ok.

Do you have any advices?

Comment: Wiki? Wiki? Wiki?